# Do summoned creatures get any bonuses to attack from the summoner?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, summoning, artificer

Do summoned creatures get any bonuses from their summoner?  I'm wondering if they use the summoner's item enhancement bonuses or get any other bonus to attack and damage rolls.

Our artificer has several summonable creatures, such as [Clockwork Acid Wasp](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7673), but their attack bonus and damage dealt seem fairly low compared to what the rest of the party is doing.  It seems odd to me that these things wouldn't scale with the items and level of their caster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Summoned Creature attacks scale the same way as other attacks.**

The summoned creature's attacks are actually the summoner attacking thru the summoned creature.  All modifiers are used except temporary modifiers.

From [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=85):

> Attacks and Checks: If a summoning power allows the summoned creature to attack, the summoner makes an attack through the creature, as specified in the power description.
>
> If the summoned creature can make a skill check or an ability check, the summoner makes the check. The attack or check uses the summoner’s game statistics, unless the descriptions of the power or creature specify otherwise.
>
> Attacks and checks made through the creature do not include any temporary bonuses or penalties to the summoner’s statistics.

Comment: I like this answer, but could you give a concrete example for clarification?

Comment: @JasonWhite While an example would be good, I'm not sure how it helps here. Basically use use *exactly the same* attack that the summoner has. so if the Summoner is +9 (+4 ability, +3 1/2 level, +2 implement or some such) to hit then the summon would be +9 to hit as well. The only bonus that wouldn't get added is if say a cleric gave the summoner an attack bonus, that would not get passed on (in that case he should grant the bonus to the summon, not the summoner)

Comment: @waxeagle - I'm still a little confused though. Does my Giant Toad (Melee 3, Wis vs. Ref) use the same attack chance as my Staff melee attack (Combined attack is Melee 2, Wis +19 vs. AC) or the same chance as my Staff ranged attack (Fire Hawk, Ranged 10, Wis +17 vs. Reflex). So far, since the character builder doesn't specify, I've assumed the same as the Fire Hawk, since I'm effectively making a ranged attack through my summoned creature.

Comment: @MarkBooth you use the implement based one. From the looks of it (and I'm guessing here) Combined attack is weapon and fire hawk is implement. Your giant toad is summoned via your implement and thus it's attack powers are implement based so you don't get the weapon proficiency bonus you do for combined attack.